# urlrewriting and html5mode not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs, routes

hi there am using ngRoute of angularjs with htm5lMode via $locatioProvider but if navigate to localhost:3000/profile and get the indext page without the partial loading, if i navigate to localhost:3000/#/profile the url is change to http://localhost:3000/#!#%2Fprofile and still remain on the index page. thus it only works (loading the partial) when i navigate manually to localhost:3000/#!/profile. i want to avoid hashbang url. any idea please

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/pro.html',
        controller: 'kontrola'
      })

      $locationProvider.html5Mode('true')
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')
    }])`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to pass a Boolean value to `html5Mode`. But you are passing a string.

`$locationProvider.html5Mode('true')`

this should be

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`